# Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache for port 8080 but fine on port 80?

Tags: spring, curl, dns, raspberry-pi

I am testing an API I have made using Springboot from my laptop (192.168.1.217:8080) and I am trying to get a cURL request via SSH from my Raspberry Pi.

Here is the error I am receiving when I try to send the request via port 8080 which it seems to not like:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ curl -v 192.168.1.217:8080/api
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.1.217...
```

However cURL does work for the same IP but with port 80:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ curl -v 192.168.1.217
* Rebuilt URL to: 192.168.1.217/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.1.217...
* Connected to 192.168.1.217 (192.168.1.217) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: 192.168.1.217
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Thu, 30 Mar 2017 17:20:43 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.5.38 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.5.38
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38
< Location: http://192.168.1.217/dashboard/
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html
<
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.217 left intact
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

I've tried looking around but to no avail... anybody have any suggestions as to why I cannot find my own hostname in the DNS cache?

Cheers

Comment: Would you expect an IP address to be in your DNS cache? Curl probably first tries "192.168.1.217" as a literal hostname when you include the port. Have you tried putting http:// before 192.168.1.217:8080/api in the curl command? Have you tried 192.168.1.217:80/api?

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like Apache is not listening on port 8080 in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache` is not the problem. You can clearly see on the next line, in *both* examples, that after saying that curl is trying to connect to `192.168.1.217`. Your problem is that nothing is answering on port 8080 on that IP address (while an Apache server *is* answering on port 80 there).

If you're getting a long pause and then a timeout rather than a quick "Connection refused", you almost certainly need to open port 8080 in the local firewall on your server machine.

Answer (score 1):

curl without a protocol prefix presumes HTTP port 80.

To use another port, where it does not make that assumption, all you need to do is change your command's URL to be like this:

```
curl -v http://192.168.1.217:8080/api
```

Here is a decent article on the subject:  [Using CURL For Testing Web Applications](https://brainflush.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/using-curl-for-testing-web-applications/)

Comment: Unfortunately it just still gets stuck on the same error:
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache

*   Trying 192.168.1.217...

Comment: sounds like you have some sort of DNS problem. I bet if you put 129.168.1.217:80 you see the same problem.